# Binding in xaml with a parameterized contructor

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-store-apps, viewmodel

I'm currently trying to bind to data from a class with a parameterized constructor and I'm having trouble figuring out how to get xaml to use that constructor instead of the default one. What I want to do is have the `Value` property of my `Gauge Control` be set to equal the number of entries returned by my `IMobileServiceTableQuery` shown in the `GetDoDo method`.

My viewmodel class `StatsViewModel` looks like this:

```
class StatsViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private int _value;

    // Default constructor
    public StatsViewModel() { }

    public StatsViewModel(int val)
    {
        _value = val;
    }

    public int Value {
        get { return _value; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref _value, value); }
    }
}
```

Then in my xaml.cs file I have a `GetToDo` method which queries a table in Azure and sets the Value property in the viewmodel to equal the number of rows returned by the query:

```
private async void GetTodo()
{
    ImobileServiceTableQuery<int> query = taskTable
        .Where(t => t.Status == 1)
        .Select(t => t.Status);

    List<int> statusOne = await query.ToListAsync();

    int val = statusOne.Count;

    StatsViewModel stats = new StatsViewModel(val);

    /******************************************************************************
     * This is something I tried earlier but it didn't
     * work so I commented it out:
     *
     * Binding valueBinding = new Binding();
     * valueBinding.Source = stats;
     * BindingOperations.SetBinding(ToDoGauge, Gauge.ValueProperty, valueBinding);
     *
     * Was I on the right track here?
     *******************************************************************************/
}
```

Finally the relevant code in my xaml looks like this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    ...
    <viewmodels:StatsViewModel x:Name="StatsViewModel" />
</Page.Resources>

...

<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="To Do Items:" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
    <controls:Gauge
        x:Name="ToDoGauge"
        Minimum="0"
        Maximum="100"
        Height="200"
        Value="{Binding Value}"
        Unit="To Do" FontFamily="Global User Interface" />
</StackPanel>
```

I'm pretty sure the issue has to do with the fact that the constructor is parameterized, because when I stepped through the code I was able to verify that the number of items in the list I query in `GetToDo()` gets assigned accurately to `_value` in `StatsViewModel`. My thinking is that the xaml code just looks at the default constructor, see's that nothing is defined there and assumes Value is an empty value. What I don't understand is how to get the xaml code to see the value of _value set in the parameterized constructor.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: _"can't get it to work"_ is a horrible problem statement.

Comment: Your ToDo() has nothing whatsoever to do with the static resource.

Comment: Okay, but is there something I should be doing differently in my `StatsViewModel` class or should I set the binding up in my `ToDo` method? That was my reason for including it.

Comment: You're still not stating actual vs expected results, the edit didn't help a lot.

Comment: `Source={StaticResource` will not connect to anything you do in C#. Consult a basic tutorial on databinding.

Comment: Initially I didn't have the Source value there (and have since removed it again). I've looked at a number of sources online and haven't found any that really fit this specific problem. Do you know how (or of a source that I could consult) to bind to the Value property in my `StatsViewModel` class and have it update based on what happens in `GetToDo()`?

Comment: Typically, you put the view model into the `DataContext`, not the control's Resources. In GetTodo, either you update the instance already in the DataContext or you create a new instance and set it to the DataContext.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I ended up just using a workaround that brings about the desired result without actually solving the problem of binding to this data in xaml but here's what I did:

```
private async void GetToDo()
{

    ...

    double value = Double(Parse(val.ToString());

    ToDoGauge.SetValue(Gauge.ValueProperty, value);

}
```

When I figure out how to get the binding working properly, I'll edit this answer for anyone who might have a similar question down the road. If someone does know how to fix this feel free to post--I'd love to see what some alternate solutions look like.